# I have nissan 240 1985 problem in electricity the problem

Tags: engine, electrical, battery, nissan

I have nissan 240 1985 problem in electricity the problem is I start my vehicle normally without any problem. When I want to off my engine I turn the ignition switch off and the engine won't stop, still idling. The weirdest thing was when I turn on the headlights my engine stops. So how can I solve this problem? 
Please, I want the best steps to solve this problem quickly because it is a customer car

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check all the earth straps / leads between engine / body / battery as engine stopping when you turn on the headlights is a classic earthing symptom.